# Mixed Models : Effect of Adding Individual Level Predictor on Between Group Residual Variance

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

This is a portion of a tutorial from the [Centre for Multi-Level Modeling](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/) regarding random intercept models.

Can anyone explain why this scenario is so? It seems like by the logic given and that the u_j (group effects) are moved toward zero by adding the new predictor, the variance of the u_j would DECREASE not increase.

[image]

[image]